# Application.vent or trigger('eventname') to parent until it reaches your controller?

Tags: marionette

I'm just starting my second marionettejs app. I'm using requirejs for it. 
I'm kind of confused how I should handle my events triggered from a sub view on my controller (e.g. controller->compositeView->itemview or controller->compositeview->layout->compositeview->itemview)

I've tried these and both are working properly :
- application.vent
- have the immediate parent listen and then trigger the same event and have its parent listen to it and repeat this process until it reaches the controller

My question is which one should i use or which one is preferred?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer to let controller to handle `App.vent` when possible.

In your case, the controller normally has responsibility the prepare the compositeView, so it's easy for the controller to listen to events in the composteView's itemViews, with a prefix `itemview`

Let's say you have an itemView

```
class QuestionView extends Marionette.ItemView
  triggers:
    'click .read-more' : 'read:more:clicked'
```

Then a compositeView

```
class QuestionsView extends Marinontee.CompositeView
  itemView: QuestionView
```

Then in controller normally you need to prepare the compositeView

```
questionsView = new QuestionsView
  collection: question
```

**Now you can easily listen to events in Question itemView within this controller with 'itemview' prefix**, and then trigger the App level vent with this **exact itemView** as argument.

```
@listenTo questionsView, 'itemview:read:more:clicked', (itemView) ->
  App.vent.trigger 'process:this:view:event', (itemView)
```

Comment: thank you very much for this answer. really cleared up a lot for me.